# Error: "Document_KeyUp" event not working

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I'm trying to change the color of the text I'm going to type every time the `"` key is pressed in my current word document. But the `key Up` event doesn't seem to work, I even put a `MsgBox` in it to see Yes it was the key code and nothing.

> Note: The document is enabled for macros and in security options allows all macros to run.

> Note: I use Office 2013

This is my code:

```VisualBasic
Private Sub Document_KeyPress(ByVal KeyCode As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Static Is_Str As Boolean
    
    If KeyCode = 34 Then
        ' The key was pressed "
        If Is_Str Then
            ' End Str
            Selection.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Else
            ' Init Str
            Selection.Font.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End If
        Is_Str = Not Is_Str
    End If
    'I put this in to make sure that if the function is called when a key is pressed
    MsgBox "A key has been pressed"
End Sub
```

This is the structure of my project:
[image]

And how I want it to be executed:
[image]

Question translated from Spanish:

- [Evento Document_KeyUp no funciona](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/616955/205933)

Comment: The `Document_KeyPress` event doesn't exist in Word.

Answer (score 1):

The resolve for this issue  needs to create  a Class with the WindowSelectionChange event.

Insert a Class module the name will be `Class1` with this code

```
Public WithEvents myclass As Word.Application


Private Sub myclass_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
MsgBox "A button was pressed"
End Sub
```

In the ThisDocument modul insert this:

```
Dim X As New Class1
Sub init()
Set X.myclass = Word.Application
End Sub
```

After running this sub the event will be invoked if you change the selection on the word document even if repositioning the cursor.

Microsoft documentation:

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.windowselectionchange)

and

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/objects-properties-methods/using-events-with-the-application-object-word)

Comment: Thanks, it works with the mouse. Do you know how to get the keyboard events, like key up, key down...

Comment: It looks like Word.Application doesn't have it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application

Comment: This works for selection change, therefore if you type text this not invokes but if you move the cursor with keyboard buttons, it is involved. (e.g. arrows or Home). Yes it hasnt Key events. One workaround is `KeyBinding` for every key button.

Comment: If I'm honest, I don't know whether to mark your answer as accepted.  Tomorrow I'll investigate that class and see if I get the result.  Thanks for the help.